# Is there any css/html to write a text without fill color only stroke?

Tags: css

i'm new and looking for help.
I need to write a heading text or title without fill color only stroke as the design need.
the thing is "Organic
Product"
I need the organic to be as it is

Organic
but the product needs to be only stroke without fill color.
Help me.
thanks for reading.

Comment: Oh man... I know there's really people very good (not me) searching at google but this is not the case. Just search "css text stroke" and done! https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-stroke`, `background-clip` combination of CSS properties. [Check caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke-color) for compatibility chart.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  text-align:center;
}
h1 {
  font: bold 48px/64px monospace;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h1>STROKED TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! worked.

Comment: @MdHridoyHasanApurbo Mark it as accepted answer